# When was Dire warned about time travelers?

Tags: dire-saga

Early in *Dire: Seed*, Timetripper shows up, provoking the following line:

> “AH. A TIME TRAVELER, THEN?” I felt my lips curl back. People like him were the reason I’d erased my old memory, hidden my past from myself.

I went ahead and reread the first book, *Dire: Seed*, assuming there was something in the beginning or the end (the two places Dire gets some info from her past self) but no dice. When did she realize this was the reason for her amnesia?

Comment: Perhaps she deduced it? From what little I know about the series, isn’t she some sort of genius mad scientist supervillain?

Comment: That is possible. There are also two short stories I have not read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [asked the author](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/916083-early-in-dire-seed-timetripper-shows) whether this is a reference to text in the first book and he said:

> Got it in one. There's one of the chapter opening screeds in Dire:Born that goes into greater detail about this.

I suspect that he's talking about one of the "Dire Monologues" that heads some of the chapters, probably Excerpt #47 (heading chapter 3):

> "The advantage of this approach, is that you're going in as a virtual unknown...."

I asked for further clarification, but have not gotten a reply yet. Among other things, the way in which the Monologues are described sound like they were tapes Dire did not listen to until much later (having been retrieved by the MRB from the wreckage of the first lair).

There were some further revelations in later books, namely that

> Dire's thoughts and actions are guided by a group of synthetic intelligences from the future.

This means that there is no contradiction that Dire is acting on something that might otherwise be considered future knowledge.